# Check date time before sending user data

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My table has 3 `datetime` values: `AcceptStart`, `AcceptEnd`, `AcceptExtra`

I want to check these 3 `datetime` values against `DateTime.Now`. I use below conditions to check datetime against the current time. User can only send file if today is between `AcceptStart` and `AcceptEnd`. Also if `AccpetExtra` has a value, user can send file if today is less then `AcceptExtra`

```
if(Config.AcceptStart.Value >= DateTime.Now)
     return "notstart";

if(Config.AcceptEnd.Value >= DateTime.Now)
     return "DateEnded";

if(Config.AcceptExtra.HasValue && Config.AcceptExtra.Value > DateTime.Now)
     return "DateEnded";
```

Is my code correct?

Is there any better solution for my problem?

Comment: You will need to provide more context.  It looks to me like AcceptEnd should be `<` though.

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns i have course and course registration is limited to certain datetime and also admin can add extradate for extend register end time